# Change Select2 to display 'n of m items selected'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I like to use the Select2 plugin with tagging enabled, like in this example:
https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags

However I would like to change it to display a text like

> n of m items selected

when there are more than say 3 items selected. Once you click the box you would see the exact items, like it is now.

Then the select box could be rendered much smaller and consume less space.

This does not seem to be a config option. Do you have an idea, where in the code to change this behavior?

Comment: you probably want anything like this http://jsfiddle.net/mL44s7rr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easy like this. No rape select2 is needed :)

```
$("#singleSelectExample").select2({
  closeOnSelect: false
});

$('#singleSelectExample').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $(this).val().length; 
  var of = $(this).find('option').length;
  $(this).parent().find('.select2-selection ul').html('Selected ' + selected + ' of ' + of + '  items.')
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rtwmL35y/)

Comment: templateSelection allows me to change the display text of the option selected. But it adds for each selection a new item into the search field.

Answer (score 1):

https://select2.github.io/examples.html#events

With event you can do it. Fire the select event and update your text.