# How to limit number of displayed tags in select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I need to limit the number of displayed selected tags. Please notice that I do not want to restrict the maximum number of selected tags. So a user should be able to select as many options as he wants but I want to have control over how selected tags are displayed.

For example, I might want to just show a text like: `5 items are selected`.
I tried to use `templateSelection` config parameter but this function is called per selected option so I cannot return a single label for multiple selected options.

Also I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786092/change-select2-to-display-n-of-m-items-selected) answer but it's not working(setting the html inside change callback does not anything) and it seems more like a hack.

Is there some built-in or better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

In this example you can define after how many selected you want to show the text using the condition `if (selected > 4)`. Or remove that condition to have the text show for any input.

```js
$("#singleSelectExample").select2({
  closeOnSelect: false
});

$("#singleSelectExample2").select2();

$('#singleSelectExample').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $(this).val().length;
  var of = $(this).find('option').length;

  if (selected > 4)
    $(this).parent().find('.select2 .select2-selection ul').html('Selected ' + selected + ' of ' + of +'  items.')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="singleSelectExample" multiple style="width: 300px;">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
  <option value="6">Option 6</option>
  <option value="7">Option 7</option>
  <option value="8">Option 8</option>
  <option value="9">Option 9</option>
  <option value="10">Option 10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found [this great article](https://bojanv91.github.io/posts/2017/10/extending-select2-with-adapters-and-decorators) about adapters which also contains working jsfiddle.